# Autofill listbox from textbox text VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want a userform where as text is being typed into `textbox1`, possible values that match the text from the sheet "Data" populate `listbox1` and similarly for `textbox2` and `listbox2`. Currently when I type in `textbox1`, it's filling `listbox2` with values from column A in the sheet that is open, instead of the sheet "Data".

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim i As Integer, ws As Worksheet
ListBox1.Visible = True

Set ws = Sheets("Data")
    For i = 2 To Sheets("Data").Range("D6000").End(xlUp).Row
        If UCase(Left(ws.Cells(i, 1), Len(TextBox1.Text))) = UCase(TextBox1.Text) Then
            ListBox1.AddItem Cells(i, 1)
            End If
            Next i
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
Dim i As Integer, ws As Worksheet
ListBox2.Visible = True
Set ws = Sheets("Data")
    For i = 2 To Sheets("Data").Range("B6000").End(xlUp).Row
        If UCase(Left(ws.Cells(i, 1), Len(TextBox2.Text))) = UCase(TextBox2.Text) Then
            ListBox2.AddItem Cells(i, 1)
            End If
            Next i
End Sub
```

Edit: What I ended up using:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim i As Long
Dim arrList As Variant

Me.ListBox1.Clear
If Sheet7.Range("D" & Sheet7.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 1 And Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value) <> vbNullString Then
    arrList = Sheet7.Range("D1:D" & Sheet7.Range("D" & Sheet7.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    For i = LBound(arrList) To UBound(arrList)
        If InStr(1, arrList(i, 1), Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value), vbTextCompare) Then
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem arrList(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
End If
If Me.ListBox1.ListCount = 1 Then Me.ListBox1.Selected(0) = True


End Sub
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

Dim i As Long
Dim arrLists As Variant

Me.ListBox2.Clear
If Sheet7.Range("B" & Sheet7.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 1 And Trim(Me.TextBox2.Value) <> vbNullString Then
    arrLists = Sheet7.Range("B1:B" & Sheet7.Range("B" & Sheet7.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    For i = LBound(arrLists) To UBound(arrLists)
        If InStr(1, arrLists(i, 1), Trim(Me.TextBox2.Value), vbTextCompare) Then
            Me.ListBox2.AddItem arrLists(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
End If
If Me.ListBox2.ListCount = 1 Then Me.ListBox2.Selected(0) = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Qualify the range... `Sheets("Data").Cells(r,c)`.  You could use `With ws` and do `.cells()` or list `ws.cells()`

Comment: When you use `Range("D6000")`, there is no "qualifying reference" to which worksheet you are getting the range. So you should ALWAYS specifically qualify each time you use `Range` or `Cells` with a worksheet reference, as @Cyril and @avb both mention.

Comment: I have edited the code above to reflected changes but it is still not autopopulating the listboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ws.Cells(i, 1)` instead of `Cells(i, 1)`.
Also, should the part concerning `ListBox2` be moved to `TextBox2_Change()` ?

Comment: Definetly makes sense! I moved the `ListBox2` code to a separate sub, but neither of the textboxes are autofilling the listboxes with data

Comment: did you add `ws` prefix?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the code above to reflect changes @avb

Comment: i reconstructed the code and it works for me - check your condition logic, also, if the condition is true you would add 5999 items to your listbox...